# Errno 10061 in python, I don't know what do to

Tags: python, sockets

I learned sockets in python. When I tried to programming sockets script in one computer, it worked, but when I tried to programming sockets script with two different computers and open socket with connection, it didn't work.

One computer(the server):

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 1234
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    c.send('Thank you for connecting')
    c.close()
```

Second computer(the client):

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()

host = raw_input("The ip you want to connect to: ")
port = 1234

s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
```

Error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 10061]
```

What is the problem in the scripts? Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Error 10061 (WSAECONNREFUSED): *“Connection refused. No connection could be made because the target computer actively refused it. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the foreign host—that is, one with no server application running.”* ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Answer (score 4):

Errno 10061:

It means the server you are trying to connect to is not waiting for one.

- Make sure you have the port number open.
- Try killing all python processes and start server again.

**Update**

Instead of

```
host = socket.gethostname()
```

use

```
host = ""
```

Comment: i checked that and i sure that the port number was open and all the python processes was killed, and still it doesn't work, what i need to do ? Thank you for your help.