# Getting started with network programming in Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am quite new to Python, and even newer to network programming.
I'm starting with this example from docs.python.org:

Server:

```
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

Client:

```
# Echo client program
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'        # The remote host
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall('Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

The original code listed some other address as host, I've changed it to
localhost. The first time I ran the programs they were stopped by the firewall,
but I let it make an exception, and that has not been a problem since.

However, neither of the programs work. The server program gets this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python\echoclient.py", line 7, in <module>
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10061] Det gick inte att göra en anslutning eftersom måldatorn aktivt nekade det
```

("A connection could not be made because the target computer actively denied it")

The client program gets this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last
File "C:\Users\Python\echoclient.py", line 9, in <module> data = s.recv(1024)
error: [Errno 10054] En befintlig anslutning tvingades att stänga av fjärrvärddatorn
```

("Existing connection was forced to close by remote host")

I am using Python 2.7.6. How do I make this work?

Comment: I'd say you still have a firewall blocking your connection. Or try running the server as an administrator (shouldn't need to tho, but might as well try that).

Comment: I discovered that it worked when you run it from the command line. It still does not work when I run it in IDLE.

Comment: That's because the IDLE starts the `python` process, but the owner of that process is most likely the IDLE, so you'll need to add that to your firewall settings :)

Answer (score 1):

Question already asked here : [Errno 10061 in python, I don't know what do to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664424/errno-10061-in-python-i-dont-know-what-do-to)

When you have a problem with a network connection on windows, check the [Errno number](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819124) to understand.

In your case, since you are running the app on localhost, maybe you have a firewall rule blocking the server script to bind with port on machine.

To check if app is listening:

On windows, open a cmd prompt (run as Administrator):

```
netstat -ban | findstr "50007"
```

On Linux :

```
netstat -ltnp | grep 50007
```

=> If you don't see anything returned, it means nothing is listening on this port.

=> If you see something, check it is your app.

If so, check your firewall rules, antivirus ( best is to disable all sec if you are troubleshooting and it is a test machine)

On windows, go to firewall settings

On Linux, `iptables -L -n` as root ( or sudo)

Comment: I use Windows. I tried to enter the netstat command to the command line, but I get no response. Is this good or bad?
How can I see if I have a firewall rule?

Comment: What is your OS version?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional

Comment: I'm not sure what ypu are refering to when you say 'AV'. This computer has no external units except for it's network connection.

Comment: Make sure you circumvent UAC in window, run your command prompt where you run server as administrator, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry AV == Anti-Virus