# i got error 10061 in python

Tags: python, sockets, server

im trying to send a message to myself in python but the client code gives me error 10061 the server works properly  it worked just fine but than it suddenly started giving me the error. i tried changing the port but it still gives me the same error

the server

```
from socket import *
from datetime import *
def main():
    s = socket()
    client_socket = None
    s.bind(("127.0.0.1",8200))
    print "1:time"
    print "2:get list of files"
    print "3:download file"
    print "4:quit"
    input()
    s.listen(1)
    client_socket, client_address = s.accept()
    strn=client_socket.recv(4096)
    if int(strn[0])>4 or int(strn[0])<1:
        print "please send a num between 1-4"
    elif int(strn[0])==1:
        print datetime.time(datetime.now())
    elif int(strn[0])==2:
        folder=raw_input("enter the name of the folder")
        dir(folder)
    client_socket.close()
    s.close()
    input()
if name == '__main__':
        main()
```

the client

```
from socket import *
def main():
    s = socket()
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1",8200))
    buf = raw_input()
    s.send(buf)
    s.close()
    input()
if name == '__main__':
    main()
```

the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\client.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\client.py", line 4, in main
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1",8200))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664424

Comment: always add (in question) full error message.

Comment: s.connect(("Ip",8200))/s.bind(("Ip",8200)) --> Instead of "Ip" you should put an actual IP address

Comment: i know when i run the code i use a real IP its just for the example

Comment: You can put `127.0.0.1` in the question, then. There's no reason to obscure your localhost ip

Comment: thanks i changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind i fixed it the problem was that the input was before the listen and it stalled the program thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

10061 error occurs when the target machine refuses a connection.
In your case the most likely reason is the "IP" in s.bind and s.connect try putting an actual IP or 127.0.0.1. It should work